# what hosts support Catalyst Framework Apps

Tags: perl, shared-hosting, catalyst

I would like to use the Perl Catalyst Framework on a Shared Hosting Service, but I don't know if there are any that do support it.  Are there minimum requirements in order to be able to run a catalyst app?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer as I have now deployed a Cat app to dotcloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a demo of deploying a perl app (it wasn't Catalyst based, but that's neither here nor there) to [DotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) at our local Perl Mongers' meeting a couple of weeks ago. Deploying a Catalyst app was discussed, and there's certainly no technical impediment. My situation is similar to yours, but my app is not quite ready for deployment.

**UPDATE**

I have now successfully deployed my Catalyst app on dotcloud, and have been quite pleased with the results. It's been running there now for a couple of weeks, and I have found the dotcloud environment quite easy to work with, as far as pushing new code, restarting the service and so on is concerned. There is [official documentation](http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/perl/), and a [Catalyst-specific walk-through](http://onionstand.blogspot.com/2011/04/catalyst-in-cloud.html).

More recently, Phillip Smith has recently written an [updated, Catalyst-specific guide](http://blogs.perl.org/users/phillip_smith/2011/08/dotcloud-loves-catalyst-apps-up-and-running-in-10-minutes-perl-in-the-cloud-part-iii.html).

Answer (score 4):

- Perl 5.8.4: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/META.yml
- Catalyst::Runtime and its dependencies: http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Catalyst::Runtime
- a Web server: http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/deployment

Or trade money for time and convenience and pick a managed hosting provider: http://wiki.catalystframework.org/wiki/hosting

Comment: Could you be more specific? From my point of view: perl web development stands behind the Wall. And the Wall is made from module dependencies. I don't know scenario, how to satisfy dependencies on shared host **without** shell access. Almost all shared host solutions don't have access to shell, AFAIK.

Comment: That's a different topic, go [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: What i ask is exactly what OP asked, so i think your answer in this form was blurry. I hoped you have more deep knowledge and experience.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamhost have a good hosting where you can install Catalyst and whatever you want. Basically you need an account, a 'shell' user type and a registered domain. With this items you can access the server through ssh tunnel and install the Catalyst packages.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Dotcloud is awesome.

I've just bought a Webfusion VPS (I'm working there so I figured some inside knowledge might be available).

Running up perlbrew, cpanm and my Cat app (which had a good Makefile.PL) was trivial. Getting nginx to play nicely has been harder.